# Displaying a Custom Post Type Attachment via Shortcode in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am very new and unskilled with PHP, but have found some code that seems to come close to what I am requiring.  I am using the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin to create a custom post type called Announcements that has field type of file.

I want to display the attached file on the front end via shortcode. I have found some code that pulls the field ID and not the attached file itself.  I am not sure how to change the code to suit.  Apologies for my lack of knowledge.

```
add_shortcode('field', 'shortcode_field');

function shortcode_field($atts){
     extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                  'post_id' => NULL,
               ), $atts));
  if(!isset($atts[0])) return;
 $field = esc_attr($atts[0]);
       global $post;
       $post_id = (NULL === $post_id) ? $post->ID : $post_id;
       return get_post_meta($post_id, $field, true);
}
```

Comment: 1. `extract` makes no sense how it is used there, remove that. 2. Once you got the post id, use https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: Apologies CBroe, my PHP knowledge is terrible.  Any chance you can show me what that code would look like if the file I am trying to display is a PDF and the field name is announcement_file?

Comment: Had some offline help based on your feedback @CBroe.  Got it working, thank you!